# How to set number of partitions for structured streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

```
val jsonDF = spark.readStream.format("json").schema(schema).load("source")
val result = jsonDF.groupBy("origin").sum("value")
val query = result.writeStream.outputMode("complete").format("console").start()
```

the partitions are always 200

The doc doesn't mention much : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html 
It only says that it is possible to set when using rate source with the option of 'numPartitions'

I have tried to set it in the readstream in the following ways:
spark.readStream.format("json").schema(schema)**.option("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",6)**.load("source")
spark.readStream.format("json").schema(schema)**.option("numPartitions",6)**.load("source")

No effect at all. the partition is always 200 and because of this even a simple query is slow as hell.

Comment: Did you see "Updating the value of conf 'spark.sql.shuffle.partitions' in current session from '6' to '200'." in your logs?

Comment: @RonakJain  nope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to set the config on Spark session level and not on query level.
The documentation was unclear about it.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",6)
```